# Left nullspace different than nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Can the left nullspace be different than the nullspace of a matrix?

Can the nullspace of the transpose matrix be different than the nullspace of the original matrix?

I guess it can be since for every non-rectangular matrix the nullspace and the nullspace will have different dimension , but is there a general rule?

Answer (score 1):

Null space is related to columns and left null space is related to the rows then they are in general different but an important property holds, also for rectangular matrices, their codimension is the [**rank**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of the matrix.

Comment: @Arthur Opsss yes of course! I fix that! I was thinking to $C(A)$ :)

Comment: user but since we have 2 different matrices , their rank should be different.

Comment: @HelenaWells $r=Rank A = Rank A^T$ and since $dim(C(A))=dim(C(A^T))$ by Rank-Nullity theorem obtain the result.

Comment: @HelenaWells Refer to the given link and notably to [that proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_=_row_rank).

Comment: @user Contrary to your first comment, we cannot deduce that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same rank using the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I mean that we can deduce that dimension of nullspace and left nullspace are $n-r$ and $m-r$ from rank-nullity theorem. Am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: @user We can deduce that the nullspace has dimension $n - \dim C(A)$ and the left nullspace has dimension $m - \dim C(A^T)$, but I don't see how that helps

Comment: @user What we *could* do is use the fact that the nullspace has dimension $n - \dim C(A)$ together with the fact that the nullspace is $C(A^T)^\perp$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Are you referring to the fact that given $rank(A)=r$, since the dimension of the null space is $n-r$ and it is orthogonal to the row space therefore also the dimension of row space is $r$, that is $A$ and $A^T$ have the same rank?

Comment: @user Yes that's right

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah ok! That's was already clear to me mainly form Gilbert Strang "Big Picture" but probably I wasn't so clear in my comments. Thanks a lot for your kind attention. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general they are different. For an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, the vectors of the nullspace are $n$-dimensional, whereas the vectors of the left nullspace are $m$-dimensional. So if $n \neq m$, these two spaces are different. But even if $n = m$, the two spaces can be different.

For example, consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then the nullspace of $A$ is the $y$-axis, $\{ (0, y, 0): y \in \mathbb{R} \}$, whereas the left nullspace is the $z$-axis, $\{ (0, 0, z): z \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Also, something worth noting is that, because row rank equals column rank, the rank $r$ of $A$ is the same as that of $A^T$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullity (that is, the dimension of the nullspace) is $n - r$, and the dimension of the left nullspace is $m - r$.